# What does it mean to make up for prayers unavoidably missed - Tashlumin?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, tashlumin

The laws of Tashlumin (making up for prayers unavoidably missed) are delineated in [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tashlumin)

> “If one forgot to say Shacharit one should say Mincha twice, the first
>   for Mincha and the second as a makeup (Tashlumin) of Shacharit.” Etc.

To whom are we “making up” when we do tashlumin? I find it difficult to think that HaShem is so to speak missing that prayer.

Should we think rather that our Rabbis gave us the opportunity to make up for the lost opportunity to make a connection to HaShem?

Comment: Not just the lost opportunity for a connection, but the lost opportunity for a mitzvah — רצה הקב"ה לזכות את ישראל

Comment: מתאוה תפילתן של צדיקים??? Hashem doesn't want prayers?! Of course He does

Comment: @Mefaresh Is tashlumin only for tzaddikim then?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't think I implied that. Just arguing on your premise that Hashem isn't "missing" the prayer

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://etzion.org.il/he/%D7%9B%D7%95-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F) by Rabbis Aviad Bartov and Noam Malchi suggests three possible conceptual understandings of *tefillat tashlumin*.

1. As an opportunity to ‘fix’ the omission of the previous prayer.
2. As a fine for having missed the previous prayer.
3. As the actual prayer that was missed, being prayed at a non-ideal time.